# Does the OpenID Connect Core specification incorrectly define the OpenID Provider and Relying Party in terms of human participants?

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

There are a few important definitions in the [OpenID Connect Core specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) that refer to a human participant, and at first glance it would seem that OpenID Connect only applies in cases where there is a human participant, but this is not true in practice.  Are these terms incorrectly defined in terms of human participation, and should they have been defined more generally to encompass usage where there is no human participation?

Here are the definitions, with other defined terms also in bold (those definitions are listed below as well):

- **End-User**: Human participant
- **OpenID Provider**: OAuth 2.0 **Authorization Server** that is capable of **Authenticating** the **End-User** and providing **Claims** to a **Relying Party** about the **Authentication** event and the **End-User**
- **Relying Party**: OAuth 2.0 **Client** application requiring **End-User** **Authentication** and **Claims** from an **OpenID Provider**

Despite the existence of the above human-centric term definitions, there are many other relevant definitions in the specification that either explicitly state or imply that a human participant is unnecessary.  Given these additional definitions (see below), it is clear that the use of OAuth 2/OpenID Connect in a context without human interaction is reasonable -- and in fact it is widely supported.  Here are those definitions:

- **Entity**: Something that has a separate and distinct existence and that can be identified in a context. An **End-User** is one example of an Entity *(implying there are other examples that are not human participants)*.
- **ID Token**: JSON Web Token (JWT) that contains **Claims** about the **Authentication** event. It MAY contain other **Claims**.
- **Authentication**: Process used to achieve sufficient confidence in the binding between the **Entity** and the presented **Identity**.
- **Identity**: Set of attributes related to an **Entity**.
- **Claim**: Piece of information asserted about an **Entity**.

The OpenID Connect Core specification uses several terms defined by the [OAuth 2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) that support the notion of interaction without human involvement:

- **Resource Owner**: **Entity** capable of granting access to a protected resource.  When the **Resource Owner** is a person it is referred to as an **End-User** *(implying there are other examples that are not people)*.
- **Resource Server**: Server hosting protected resources, capable of accepting and responding to protected resource requests using **Access Tokens**.
- **Client**: Application making protected resource requests on behalf of the **Resource Owner** and with its authorization.
- **Authorization Server**: Server issuing **Access Tokens** to the **Client** after successfully authenticating the **Resource Owner** and obtaining authorization
- **Access Token**: Credentials used to access protected resources; it is a string representing an authorization issued to the **Client**.

Given all of this, I can't help but think that the definitions of **OpenID Provider** and **Relying Party** should have referred to **Entity** instead of **End-User**.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

No, the definitions are correct.

Keep in mind that a relying party does not authenticate but gets authorised through the process where the end user first authenticated and then supplied an authorisation (in the form of a token) to the relying party.

More clarification on your final comment:

- The OpenID provider does not Authenticate any Entity, it is specifically an Authorisation Server capable of Authenticating a human END USER.
- The Relying Party is an application, either running on a server or on a user's device.  A human User needs to have Authenticated prior to a token being provided to the Relying party, hence the work End User in the definition.

Comment: What about the case where a confidential **Client** authenticates to the **Authorization Server** via the OAuth 2 Client Credentials grant type by providing its `client_id` and `client_secret`?  At least with WSO2 Identity Server such a client will receive both an **Access Token** and an **ID Token** even though the flow is a pure OAuth 2 flow rather than one of the three that OpenID Connect defines.  There is indirect human involvement here -- someone has to define what the confidential client can do and arrange for that information to make it into the JWTs -- but no direct human involvement.

Answer (score -1):

**OpenID Provider** is a server.

**Relying Party** is an application.

Sure, servers and applications don't appear on their own. Humans develop applications, humans deploy and configure them, humans define security policies. But we don't consider how it was **configured**. We consider how it **acts**.